# $\iota \equiv \pm 3, \pmod{10}$

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, fake-proofs

I was reading up on the properties modulo function, when I saw the property:

$$-a \equiv (10-a) \space \pmod{10}$$

Which means

$$-1 \equiv (10-1) \equiv 9 \space \pmod{10}$$

Now:
$$\iota = \sqrt{-1}$$

Substituting $-1 \equiv 9 \pmod{10}$:

$$\iota \equiv \sqrt{9} \pmod{10}$$
$$\iota \equiv \pm 3 \pmod{10}$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Usually, modular arithmetic is done only with integers, $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is not even a real number.

Comment: You don't get $\sqrt{9}$ first of all, you get $10 - i \neq \sqrt{9}$ when you substitute. Secondly, those properties of modular arithmetic don't trivially carry over to $\mathbb{C}... $ you need  to handle the real and imaginary parts

Comment: Moreover, we do not have $$x^2\equiv y^2\mod n\implies x\equiv \pm y\mod n$$ so we cannot "take the square root" in modular congruences.

Comment: @Peter But $-1$ is a real number, and I think that there is a theorem (but I cannot find it right now) that if an equation is true, then taking the modulus of that equation is also true.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I am substituting the value of $-1$ into the square root. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Peter Why not? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: We have $9^2\equiv 2^2\mod 77$ , but $9\ne \pm 2\mod 77$

Comment: @Peter But we do have $$x \equiv y \pmod{n} \implies x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod{n}$$, right?

Comment: @KartikSoneji Yes, this direction is right.

Comment: OK, then. I understand. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the statement that $3 = \sqrt{-1} \pmod{10}$, which only means that $3^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$. Similarly $\sqrt{7} = 5 \pmod{18}$ because $5^2 \equiv 17 \pmod{18}$. It is not clear what the question is asking, but there is no contradiction.

Comment: @CarlMummert The contradiction is that $\iota$ should not be equal to a real number, even in mod n.

Comment: You can extend to mod  **pure** real numbers. But it likely involves dealing with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part

Comment: @Kartik Soneji:. $\sqrt{-1}$ is different in every number system. In base 5, $\sqrt{-1} = 2$. In base 17, $\sqrt{-1} = 4$. Neither of these is related to square roots in the complex numbers. In base 3 there is no square root of $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion in the question is in thinking that $\sqrt{-1}$ always denotes the same number.  In the end, the expression "$\sqrt{-1}$" denotes a number whose square is $-1$.  So the meaning of the symbol $\sqrt{-1}$ depends on the multiplication operation - if we switch to a different multiplication operation, we can get a different meaning for some square roots.

- In the real numbers, there is no value for $\sqrt{-1}$ - there is no real number that is the square root of $-1$ under multiplication of real numbers.
- In the complex numbers, there are two possible values for the square root of $-1$ under multiplication of complex numbers. These are usually called $i$ and $-i$.
- If we work with integers modulo $5$, $2 = \sqrt{-1}$, because $2^2 = 4 \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$. But $4$ is not a square root of $-1$, modulo $5$, because $4^2 = 16 \equiv 1 \not \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$.  The number $3$ is the other possible value for $\sqrt{-1}$, modulo $5$.
- If we work with integers modulo $17$, now we have $4 = \sqrt{-1}$, because $4^4 = 16 \equiv -1 \pmod{17}$. The other square root of $-1$, modulo $17$, is $13$, which is $-4 \pmod{17}$.
- If we work modulo 3, there is no square root of $-1$, because $1^2 \equiv 2^2 \equiv 1 \not \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$.

There is nothing special about square roots here. For example, modulo $5$ we have $1/2 = 2^{-1} \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$, because $3$ multiplied by $2$ gives $1$, modulo $5$. Of course the real numbers $1/2$ and $3$ are different, but when we work with a different multiplication operation the meaning of fractions can be different.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, the problem is that $i$ is not an integer, so the typical modular arithmetic doesn't really make sense here. However, there's a way to get something similar, by working with the gaussian integers $\mathbb Z[i]$, which is the set of complex numbers with integer comoponents together with the usual addition and multiplication. Suppose we take the principal ideal $(10)\subseteq\mathbb Z[i]$,  then we look at the image of the elements of $\mathbb Z[i]$ under the natural ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z[i]\to\mathbb Z[i]/(10)$ (here, we are "looking at the gaussian integers mod $10$"). We do indeed have
$$ i^2=-1=9=3^2=7^2\pmod{10}. $$
But the problem with concluding that $i=3$ or $7$ is that in general, $x^2=y^2$ does not imply $x=y$. It does not even imply $x=\pm y$. That's only true in the field of real numbers. To take a much easier example, note that
$$ 1^2=3^2=5^2=7^2=1\pmod{8},$$
but obviously, $1,3,5,7$ are not equal.

Comment: $1\equiv -7 \bmod 8$ and $3\equiv -5 \bmod 8$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Exactly, and furthermore, $1\neq\pm3$ mod $8$. The point is that the map $x\mapsto x^2$ mod $8$ is not an injection.

Comment: One can argue it's not a function ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What? Of course it is a function. Please elaborate.

Comment: I guess I was thinking in invertible functions. The inverse isn't a surjection is an equal point to yours.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That is not correct. Since it is not an injection, it does not even have an inverse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91135/discussion-between-yifan-and-roddy-macphee).